# fastest way to detect A) color and B) size of image from byte[]

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

Currently, we are determining the size, and whether or not an image contains color by converting it to a `Bitmap` and the checking the `height`/`width`, and checking the `PixelFormat` for type `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed` to detect color.

What I've noticed though, stepping through the code, it can take 3-5 seconds just to initialize this `Bitmap` (at least for a very high-resolution TIF image):

```
ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
```

Is there a faster way to check these two things, straight from the byte array, so I can avoid the slowness of the `Bitmap` class or is this just what to expect with large TIF images?

Comment: Presumably you could dig into the `tiff` file format and figure out how to read the header and extract just the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I had thought of this as well, but I am nowhere near being an imaging expert and wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: I'm by no means an expert, but looking [here](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/egff.htm) looks like as good as place to start as any. It looks like you need to read the header and that will tell you where to find the "image file directory" and that should contain tags with size and color depth.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into that!

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't quite the answer I was hoping for, so I'll leave it open still, but I do want to at least mention one possible "answer". My original problem was that loading up the `Bitmap` was slow.

I stumbled upon [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/omars/archive/2004/03/29/100941.aspx), which explains how `Image.FromStream()` has an overload that allows you to tell it not to validate the image data. By default, that is set to `true`. By using this new overload, and setting `validateImageData` to `false` - this speeds things up tremendously.

So for example:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.fileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    using (Image photo = Image.FromStream(fs, true, false))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

The author of the article, found that his code ran 93x faster (!).